# Changing a dataframe column dates type

Tags: python, pandas, types, dataset

I have a cleaned dataset within my created data frame and I am now in the process of changing the data types of the columns in it. I have tried using astype method however I am getting an error when I use it,

A second question,  how do I convert my column data types into useable datatypes that I can use in data visualisations?

I have used the astype method with no success

```
#Import data into a dataframe
raw_data = pd.read_csv('FuelPrices2016 -2019 ulsp.csv')
raw_data.head()
Date    Pump price in pence/litre ULSP  Duty rate in pence/litre/ULSP   VAT percentage rate Unnamed: 4
0   02/01/2012  132.40  57.95   20  NaN
1   09/01/2012  132.68  57.95   20  NaN
2   16/01/2012  133.29  57.95   20  NaN
3   23/01/2012  133.72  57.95   20  NaN
4   30/01/2012  134.10  57.95   20  NaN
b


#Drop unnamed column
raw_b = raw_data.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 4',])
raw_b

Date    Pump price in pence/litre ULSP  Duty rate in pence/litre/ULSP   VAT percentage rate
0   02/01/2012  132.40  57.95   20
1   09/01/2012  132.68  57.95   20
2   16/01/2012  133.29  57.95   20
3   23/01/2012  133.72  57.95   20
4   30/01/2012  134.10  57.95   20
... ... ... ... ...
396 05/08/2019  128.37  57.95   20
397 12/08/2019  128.36  57.95   20
398 19/08/2019  128.17  57.95   20
399 26/08/2019  128.22  57.95   20
400 02/09/2019  127.86  57.95   20
401 rows × 4 columns

#Describe the data
raw_b.describe()
Pump price in pence/litre ULSP  Duty rate in pence/litre/ULSP   VAT percentage rate
count   401.000000  4.010000e+02    401.0
mean    123.043840  5.795000e+01    20.0
std 10.175522   7.114304e-15    0.0
min 101.360000  5.795000e+01    20.0
25% 115.600000  5.795000e+01    20.0
50% 123.270000  5.795000e+01    20.0
75% 130.830000  5.795000e+01    20.0
max 142.170000  5.795000e+01    20.0


#Check the types of the columns 
raw_b.dtypes
Date                               object
Pump price in pence/litre ULSP    float64
Duty rate in pence/litre/ULSP     float64
VAT percentage rate                 int64
dtype: object
c

#Change date into a string 
raw_c = raw_b.astype({'Date': str})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-64e4aadc3ce7> in <module>
----> 1 raw_d = raw_c.astype({'Date': str})

~\Anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, **kwargs)
   5855                 if col_name not in self:
   5856                     raise KeyError(
-> 5857                         "Only a column name can be used for the "
   5858                         "key in a dtype mappings argument."
   5859                     )

KeyError: 'Only a column name can be used for the key in a dtype mappings argument.'
```

​

I expect the data frame to be changed into a string but the output is this error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-64e4aadc3ce7> in <module>
----> 1 raw_d = raw_c.astype({'Date': str})

~\Anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, **kwargs)
   5855                 if col_name not in self:
   5856                     raise KeyError(
-> 5857                         "Only a column name can be used for the "
   5858                         "key in a dtype mappings argument."
   5859                     )

KeyError: 'Only a column name can be used for the key in a dtype mappings argument.'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might help? Given I can't use the data you show as input, I created a small sample dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
a = {'a1':[2,3,1],'b2':[3,2,3],'c3':['a','b','c']}
raw_1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
raw_2 = pd.DataFrame(a)
column_names = list(raw_1)
for i in column_names:
    raw_2[i] = raw_2[i].astype(object)
print(raw_1.dtypes)
print(raw_2.dtypes)
```

Here is the output for the first dataframe where the first 2 columns are of type `int` and the third one `object`:

```
a1     int64
b2     int64
c3    object
dtype: object
```

And the second dataframe, where the columns have all being changed to type `object`:

```
a1    object
b2    object
c3    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi Celius, can you use object data types as inputs for data visualisation? I would like to make a graph that plots date on the x and pump price on the y.

Comment: You want a time-series oriented graph. I would use the price as `int` or `float` in any case and date as `datetime[ns]` with `pd.to_datetime()`. However, I turned them into objects as you requested in your post: "`I expect the data frame to be changed into a string but the output is this error message`"

Comment: My apologies for not being more clear in writing, I would like to change my data frame columns into types that are more fitting for data visualisation. I have my date column and have tried this method to change only that column to DateTime, I currently have tried to nest a statement however it is not working - raw_b(pd.to_datetime(['Date']))

Comment: Would you think it would be better to create another question with the purpose better explained? Because `I expect the dataframe to be changed into a string but the output is this error message` is pretty much the opposite of what you want, which is a time series graph that would take a `datetime[ns]` type-value as x-axis and probably `int` or `float`type for your y-axis. I understand what you mean and I can help you solve the issue, but it wouldn't fully answer your question, nor what you state. If you believe that's fine for you, comment back when you've opened the new question so I read it.

Comment: Hi Celius heres the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58103122/changing-a-dataframes-data-types-for-the-express-purpose-of-using-that-data-for

Comment: Awesome, will take a look

Answer (score 0):

Question is shut, I created a better-worded question to solve my problem