# Changing a dataframes data types for the express purpose of using that data for data visualization

Tags: python, pandas, types

I have a data frame that has columns within it that are of the types: object, float 64  and int64. I want to change these types to one that I can use for data visualisations. I have tried already by using the astype method but I am getting an error.
How do I go about changing these types to one more suited for data visualization.

```
#Import data into a dataframe
raw_data = pd.read_csv('FuelPrices2016 -2019 ulsp.csv')
raw_data.head()

#Import data into a dataframe
raw_data = pd.read_csv('FuelPrices2016 -2019 ulsp.csv')
raw_data.head()
Date    Pump price in pence/litre ULSP  Duty rate in pence/litre/ULSP   VAT percentage rate Unnamed: 4
0   02/01/2012  132.40  57.95   20  NaN
1   09/01/2012  132.68  57.95   20  NaN
2   16/01/2012  133.29  57.95   20  NaN
3   23/01/2012  133.72  57.95   20  NaN
4   30/01/2012  134.10  57.95   20  NaN


#Drop unnamed column
raw_b = raw_data.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 4',])
​
raw_b
Date    Pump price in pence/litre ULSP  Duty rate in pence/litre/ULSP   VAT percentage rate
0   02/01/2012  132.40  57.95   20
1   09/01/2012  132.68  57.95   20
2   16/01/2012  133.29  57.95   20
3   23/01/2012  133.72  57.95   20
4   30/01/2012  134.10  57.95   20
... ... ... ... ...
396 05/08/2019  128.37  57.95   20
397 12/08/2019  128.36  57.95   20
398 19/08/2019  128.17  57.95   20
399 26/08/2019  128.22  57.95   20
400 02/09/2019  127.86  57.95   20
401 rows × 4 columns


#Describe the data
raw_b.describe()
Pump price in pence/litre ULSP  Duty rate in pence/litre/ULSP   VAT percentage rate
count   401.000000  4.010000e+02    401.0
mean    123.043840  5.795000e+01    20.0
std 10.175522   7.114304e-15    0.0
min 101.360000  5.795000e+01    20.0
25% 115.600000  5.795000e+01    20.0
50% 123.270000  5.795000e+01    20.0
75% 130.830000  5.795000e+01    20.0
max 142.170000  5.795000e+01    20.0

#Check the types of the columns 
raw_b.dtypes
Date                               object
Pump price in pence/litre ULSP    float64
Duty rate in pence/litre/ULSP     float64
VAT percentage rate                 int64
dtype: object

#Change date into a date
raw_b(pd.to_datetime(['Date']))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object)
   1978         try:
-> 1979             values, tz_parsed = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(data)
   1980             # If tzaware, these values represent unix timestamps, so we

pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64()

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-5ab1ccfbf9a4> in <module>
      1 #Change date into a date
----> 2 raw_b(pd.to_datetime(['Date']))

~\Anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    206                 else:
    207                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 208             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    209 
    210         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, box, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    792             result = _convert_and_box_cache(arg, cache_array, box)
    793         else:
--> 794             result = convert_listlike(arg, box, format)
    795     else:
    796         result = convert_listlike(np.array([arg]), box, format)[0]

~\Anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, box, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    461             errors=errors,
    462             require_iso8601=require_iso8601,
--> 463             allow_object=True,
    464         )
    465 

~\Anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object)
   1982             return values.view("i8"), tz_parsed
   1983         except (ValueError, TypeError):
-> 1984             raise e
   1985 
   1986     if tz_parsed is not None:

~\Anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object)
   1973             dayfirst=dayfirst,
   1974             yearfirst=yearfirst,
-> 1975             require_iso8601=require_iso8601,
   1976         )
   1977     except ValueError as e:

pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime_object()

pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime_object()

pandas\_libs\tslibs\parsing.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_datetime_string()

~\Anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py in parse(timestr, parserinfo, **kwargs)
   1356         return parser(parserinfo).parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1357     else:
-> 1358         return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1359 
   1360 

~\Anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py in parse(self, timestr, default, ignoretz, tzinfos, **kwargs)
    647 
    648         if res is None:
--> 649             raise ValueError("Unknown string format:", timestr)
    650 
    651         if len(res) == 0:

ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'Date')

​
```

Comment: `raw_b['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(raw_b['Date'])`.

Comment: I believe you should pass the format within the function, to be on the safe side.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing `pd.to_datetime(raw_b['Date'])` and not only `Date`? Does the column named `Date` exist in your dataframe before applying the function?

Comment: Date is a column heading that I created when I made the dataset within excel before saving as a .csv file

Answer (score 0):

The format for the objects are correct, you can try setting the 'Date' column to a datetime type by using:

```
raw_b['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(raw_b['Date'])
```

If that doesn't work, you should pass the format by using:

```
raw_b['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(raw_b['Date'], format= '%d/%m/%Y')
```

And then use this data to plot your graph.
Your next step would be to either pass the `Date` as x-axis to your plot, or to set it as index in your dataframe (because some functions are easier applied when the dates are in the index):

```
raw_b = raw_b.set_index('Date')
```

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = {'Date':['02/01/2012','09/01/2012','16/01/2012','23/01/2012','30/01/2012'],'Pump price in pence/litre ULSP':[132.40,132.68,133.29,133.72,134.10],'Duty rate in pence/litre/ULSP':[57.95,57.95,57.95,57.95,57.95],'VAT percentage rate':[20,20,20,20,20]}
raw_b = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(raw_b)
print(raw_b.dtypes)
raw_b['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(raw_b['Date'],format='%d/%m/%Y')
print(raw_b.dtypes)
print(raw_b)
raw_b = raw_b.set_index('Date')
print(raw_b)
raw_b.plot.line()
plt.show()
```

This is the first print (how it originally looks like) together with the types:

```
         Date  Pump price in pence/litre ULSP  Duty rate in pence/litre/ULSP  VAT percentage rate
0  02/01/2012                          132.40                          57.95                   20
1  09/01/2012                          132.68                          57.95                   20
2  16/01/2012                          133.29                          57.95                   20
3  23/01/2012                          133.72                          57.95                   20
4  30/01/2012                          134.10                          57.95                   20
Date                               object
Pump price in pence/litre ULSP    float64
Duty rate in pence/litre/ULSP     float64
VAT percentage rate                 int64
dtype: object
```

After applying `pd.to_datetime` and passing the correct format:

```
Date                              datetime64[ns]
Pump price in pence/litre ULSP           float64
Duty rate in pence/litre/ULSP            float64
VAT percentage rate                        int64
dtype: object
```

And this is what it looks like:

```
        Date  Pump price in pence/litre ULSP  Duty rate in pence/litre/ULSP  VAT percentage rate
0 2012-01-02                          132.40                          57.95                   20
1 2012-01-09                          132.68                          57.95                   20
2 2012-01-16                          133.29                          57.95                   20
3 2012-01-23                          133.72                          57.95                   20
4 2012-01-30                          134.10                          57.95                   20
```

Finally, after setting `Date` as index:

```
            Pump price in pence/litre ULSP  Duty rate in pence/litre/ULSP  VAT percentage rate
Date
2012-01-02                          132.40                          57.95                   20
2012-01-09                          132.68                          57.95                   20
2012-01-16                          133.29                          57.95                   20
2012-01-23                          133.72                          57.95                   20
2012-01-30                          134.10                          57.95                   20
```

Finally after creatiing the plot and showing it, this is the output:
[image]

Comment: Ok so I have tried the raw_b['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(raw_b['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y') and it is now giving me this error 

KeyError: 'Date'